# Using Angular 2 component in Angular 1 app

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am following https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html steps, namely "Using Angular 2 Components from Angular 1 Code" part.

Have created hero-detail.component.ts with following code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-detail',
  template: `
    <h2>Windstorm details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>1</div>
  `
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
}
```

Then added required code to main.ts:

```
import { upgradeAdapter } from './upgrade-adapter'; //this existed already
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component'; //added

//... here other code inbetween

angular.module('heroApp', [])
  .directive('heroDetail', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(HeroDetailComponent));
```

Now I insert `<hero-detail></hero-detail>` in my html, but see nothing. What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Directive part of code should have been added to app.ts, not main.ts.